# Is it possible to connect to already running session on Xubuntu 12.04 machine?

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop

Previously I was connecting to my Xubuntu machine1 by running on it `VNC server` first and then using `VNC client` on machine2 to connect to machine1. The problem is that i had to login anew to my desktop, so I got new X11 session, I believe.

I would like to connect to my already running X11 session if it's running. Is it possible to do that? If yes, than what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vncviewer` allows to specify the display number in the connection string:

> If you run the viewer with no arguments it will prompt you for a VNC
>   server to connect to. Alternatively, specify the VNC server as an
>   argument, e.g.:  vncviewer snoopy:2
>
> where 'snoopy' is the name of the machine, and '2' is the display
>   number of the VNC server on that machine. Either the machine name or
>   display number can be omitted. So for example ":1" means display
>   number 1 on the same machine, and "snoopy" means "snoopy:0" i.e.
>   display 0 on machine "snoopy".

Source: [manpage for vncviewer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vncviewer)

I could not find an explicit option in Remmina to specify display number, however:

> By default, a VNC server will listen for connections from a VNC viewer
>   on TCP port "5900+N", where N is the "Display Number" (usually just
>   zero). So a VNC server setup for Display-0 will listen on TCP-5900,
>   Display-1 is TCP-5901, etc.
>
> Additionally, the VNC server will listen for connections from a
>   web-browser on TCP port "5800+N", where N is as above. If you point a
>   web-browser to this port, the VNC server will automatically provide a
>   Java VNC viewer that runs right in your web-browser. This Java Viewer
>   will then exchange data with the VNC Server on the same ports a normal
>   VNC Viewer would use: "5900+N".

([source](http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=706%3aset-up-a-vnc-server-in-ubuntu&catid=37%3atech-notes&Itemid=59))

So I guess you may try to connect to a specific display by specifying port number in connection settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried using `x11vnc`, but no luck, can't connect.

Comment: Hmm... do you want to connect to an existing "real" X11 session (i.e. the one displayed on the physical monitor of the remote machine) or re-connect to a previously created "virtual" screen provided by VNC? In the first case you can use `x11vnc`, in the latter - `vncserver`. Here's a good article on configuring `x11vnc`: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/

Answer (score 3):

I install and use `vino`, and I believe it comes standard with regular Ubuntu (with a menu item called something like Remote Desktop). It puts a little icon in your system tray so you can easily access the program preferences. It works with any vnc client. You just have it start with your startup programs.
Run `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`

[image]

After you login, it connects immediately to your running desktop.